# Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Unable to verify your credentials - Twitter gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, environment-variables, twitter-gem

I'm using the [Twitter gem](http://sferik.github.io/twitter/) to try and post a list of tweets from an account on my webpage, however I keep getting the 'Unable to verify your credentials' error.

I've even put the |config| block in the controller to try and narrow down what's going on, but no donut!

The Twitter keys are correct. I just created an app and copy / pasted them directly into the config/application.yml file. And then when it didn't work, I created a new app and tried again.

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'yaml'
require 'rails/all'

config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
```

**config/application.yml**

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: '123456789'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: '123456789'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: '123456789'
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: '123456789'
```

**app/controllers/pages.html.erb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index

  @twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
    config.consumer_secret = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
    config.access_token = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
    config.access_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
  end

    @twitter.user_timeline("gem")

  end

  def help
  end
end
```

**Error Page:**

```
Twitter::Error::Forbidden in PagesController#index
Unable to verify your credentials

Extracted source (around line #12):            
  end

    @twitter.user_timeline("gem")

  end
```

There's something simple I'm screwing up, I'm sure of it. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@H-Dog please clarify. In using the application.yml, are you configuring it from the application.rb with `config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))`? and
are you sure you don't want to do twitter-auth to get necessary credentials (access_token and access_secret) for the account you want to tweet from?

Comment: Hi @olalekan-sogunle ,

I hadn't put the config = YAML path in the application.rb file.

I've just bunged it in and I'll update my original post. Unfortunately the app still gives the same 'Invalid or expired token.' error.

Comment: Also, I don't want to tweet from the app... I just want to access and display tweets from certain accounts.

Comment: Yes, so both tweeting from and displaying tweets for an account will need you to get the particular credentials (access_token and access_secret) for that account. You can do this through authentication using https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter